# Photoshop tools won't work

Tags: adobe-photoshop

It seems that randomly photoshop will decide that i am using the Scroll tool when i'm using something else (say the Brush tool). Also, selecting most menu commands/trying to open files by selecting the file and clicking the open button with my mouse will not work, or will attempting to open the Image menu with my keyboard (it just moves me to the next menu when attempting to navgiate in it)

I'm using photoshop CS4 Extended and Windows 7 (how do i always forget to include things like this?).

Comment: Are you using Vista?

Comment: Please edit the question with your version of Photoshop as well as what OS you're using.

Comment: Dumb question but have you reinstalled it to see what that does?

Comment: Somehow a combo of restarting and disabling another application i use fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you restarted the software or rebooted the computer?

Perhaps there's is something locking your mouse

I found something on the Adbobe site referring to such a problem with InDesign.

[They claim Aero Glass](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403039.html) could be the source of your problem.

> **ISSUE**
> When you try to access a tool or panel
> item in Adobe InDesign CS3by clicking
> on it, nothing happens.
>
> **REASON**
> You have Aero enabled on your Windows
> Vista system.
>
> **SOLUTION**
> Disable Windows Aero
>
> Aero is a new
> hardware-based graphical user
> interface in Windows Vista. It is
> intended to offer more advanced
> features than are available in the
> standard interface, including new
> transparencies and animations.

- Choose Start > Control Panel.
- Double click Personalization and select Window Color and Appearance.
- Select Windows Color And Appearance.
- Click Open Classic Appearance Properties For More Color Options.
- Select a Color Scheme other than Windows Aero and click OK.
- Re-create the problem behavior, and then do one of the following:

  - If the problem doesn't recur, then Aero is the cause.
  - If the problem recurs, then Aero isn't the cause. Re-enable Aero.

Comment: Hm. I'll try that but neither my tablet nor my mouse will work.

Comment: Quite odd, i had it working when i restarted when when i tabbed back to firefox and back then it broke again...

Comment: This is quite a most unusual bug. I guess i can disable the DWM for this program. Thanks!

Comment: Ok this gets stranger and stranger, it still doesn't work but takes longer to break now.

Comment: So he should experience the problem from the beginning right?

Comment: Ok i have an update, see the question.